# Why does log(xy) = log(x) + log(y) not work in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

Why does [log(*xy*) = log(*x*) + log(*y*)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x*y)) not work in SymPy?

I tried this:

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
print(simplify(log(x*y)))
print(expand(log(x*y)))
print(collect(log(x*y),x))
print(solve(log(x*y),x))
# log(x*y)
# log(x*y)
# log(x*y)
# [1/y]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

log(*xy*) = log(*x*)+log(*y*) does not always hold. More specifically, this may to problems if both *x* and *y* are negative or in the complex domain. The Wolfram Alpha link you gave also states “Alternate form assuming x and y are positive”.

To see this relation in SymPy, you have to mark the symbols `x` and `y` as positive, e.g. like this:

```
from sympy import symbols,log
x,y = symbols("x,y",positive=True)
expr = log(x*y)
expr.expand()
```

Alternatively (as hinted at by [user6655984](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6655984)) you can use the `force` hint to let SymPy assume that everything is maximally benign:

```
from sympy import log
from sympy.abc import x,y
expr = log(x*y)
expr.expand(force=True)
```